# Matrix Style Data Entry Screen in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, matrix, webforms

I want to create a matrix style data entry screen in ASP.Net Web forms. Currently, I am creating controls dynamically in a nested loop, but for this, I have to create controls on every post back, which to me does not look right.
Is there a better way to do it?
I have Zones, the rate is defined from one zone to another  [Here is the image showing the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAwnN.jpg) the User should be able to edit Tariff that is shown as A,B,C etc on in the image

Comment: Could you elaborate more on `matrix style data entry screen`? Could you show us the mock up?

Comment: I have updated the post, I hope it will make things clear

Answer (score 0):

> Matrix style data entry screen in ASP.Net Web forms. Is there a better
>   way to do it?

In ASP.NET Web Form, I normally use Telerik Grid *(you might be able to use GridView)*. It has ***multi-row edit***, and the grid becomes ***Excel*** like grids. I could not find the exact example on their site; [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/batch-editing/defaultcs.aspx) is the closest one.

The draw back is if I have to many controls, the page becomes too heavy *even if I store **View State** in **SQL Server***.

If you post too many controls, you will need to explicitly configure the following setting in web.config.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Another approach is to use [Telerik Spreadsheet](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/spreadsheet/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx), [DevExpers Spreadsheet](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxSpreadsheetDemos/Default.aspx) or [Syncfusion Spreadsheet](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnet/ejspreadsheet).